# Before dropping off, the taxi driver says: "That will be 8.50". So, why "That will be ....." instead of "That is ...."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language, will-would

A taxi driver takes his customers where they want. Then when they are there, before dropping them off, the taxi driver says how much they need to pay. For instance he says:

**"That will be 8 dollars and 50 cents."**

I wonder why he used the structure **"That will be ..."**, because we would expect **"That is 8 dollars and 50 cents."**

We know that **"will"** is for future tense and this is not it.

Also **"will"** is for guessing, and it is not that either. For instance:

*A: Who is at the door?*

*B: That will be john. (You already expect John will come.)*

I can understand both these usages. But the **"will"** in the question is different from both of these. So my question is why does the cab driver make a sentence with **"That will be ...."** to simply "tell about a fact which is already there on the screen of the taximeter"?

Comment: Not just taxi drivers, but anyone presenting a bill (check) for goods or services can say "That will be (X amount)". It's 'just the way we say it'.

Comment: What would it mean if the driver said "That is 8.50.". Would it mean something like "He is pointing at something (a board, a piece of paper, a screen etc) which has 8.50 written on it?

Comment: It would mean exactly the same. I said that people _can_ use 'will be', not that they have to.

Comment: Thanks Kate, that was informative. I understand it completely.

Comment: @yunus native speakers often omit words if they are unnecessary or implied e.g. 'That is 8.50 _that you need to pay me_'

Comment: The cab driver can even say 'that **was** 8.50', or '8.50 please', or '8.50, OK?' and be understood. At the end of a cab ride the passenger is expecting the driver to say the amount to be paid.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, that was informative, many thanks.

Comment: In many languages, including English, using the simple present can sound abrupt or even impolite. Shifting to the conditional ("That would be...") or the future ("That will be...") is a way of making the demand for money less direct and more polite.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - or you can say 'That's 8.50 _please_' and restore the politeness.